# For Sci-Fi books, what is the purchasing split between regular and ebooks?

Tags: publishing, self-publishing, ebook, science-fiction, sales

I can get the data for ALL books.  But can anyone direct me to regular/ebook purchasing data broken down by genre (specifically sci-fi)?

Comment: What was your source for the all-books data?

Comment: It's easy to find all-books data on the web.  See, for example: http://publishingunleashed.com/2013/01/11/book-vs-ebook-sales/

Comment: Ask Baen and Tor. Baen is the leader in drm free science fiction ebooks, and have been printing on dead trees since I was young. Tor likes drm.

Answer (score 1):

In [this link](http://franzabaleta.com/component/lyftenbloggie/2013/06/17/280-despegan-las-ventas-de-ebooks-independientes-) from Jun 2013, they say that in the UK, the total of ebooks sold are 12%. However, Sci-Fi has about 20% of ebook sales. It provides some links in English, but I couldn't find more info for free. Only some research to buy (and I'm not going to pay for it).